# Google maps heatmap data points are not displaying

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Building a server side app which will be using the google maps api for weighted heat maps to display some data.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps

However, my JS is not displaying the data points (displaying the map perfectly well). Any ideas?

```
  function initialize() {

    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var heatmapData = [
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.447), weight: 0.5},
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.445),
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.443), weight: 2},
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.441), weight: 3},
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.439), weight: 2},
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.437),
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.782, -122.435), weight: 0.5},

      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.447), weight: 3},
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.445), weight: 2},
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.443),
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.441), weight: 0.5},
      new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.439),
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.437), weight: 2},
      {location: new google.maps.LatLng(37.785, -122.435), weight: 3}
    ];

    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
      data: heatMapData
    });

    heatmap.setMap(map);

  }

  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization&callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  function toggleHeatmap() {
    heatmap.setMap(heatmap.getMap() ? null : map);
  }

  function changeOpacity() {
    heatmap.set('opacity', heatmap.get('opacity') ? null : 0.2);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  initialize();
```

Edit 1 - Chrome logs this:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined heatmap:68
Uncaught ReferenceError: heatMapData is not defined heatmap:45
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. VM1930:45
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=host:localhost…98x0.65918,size:1920x689,relsize:1.00,token:4b2u2h59g8,src:apiv3,ts:viv6jz net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT VM1937:1
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DDCyUJvj7n5l,ZvwOO2ZR5…_mlil,HRlFM3ZVJGn,Jx3V5n-JzIn,F-E4oUlMhVs%26z%3D12&cad=src:apiv3,ts:viv6n3 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT VM1937:1
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DMQc6u1JFizM,0Dl57QyKHf%26z%3D12&cad=src:apiv3,ts:viv6rc net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT VM1937:1
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?imp=smimps%3DOk5Wmy33jdt,Dw5TFMIYSGt%26z%3D12&cad=src:apiv3,ts:viv6tf net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT VM1937:1
```

Edit 2 - The Js is wrapped in this jade:

```
doctype 5
html
  head
    title #{title} - picycle
    style
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
      #panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5px;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -180px;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;

        border: 0.2px solid #999;
      }

    script(type='text/javascript')

<JS CODE FROM ABOVE>

  body

    #panel
      button(onclick='toggleHeatmap()') Toggle Heatmap
      button(onclick='changeOpacity()') Change opacity

    #map-canvas
```

Comment: getting any error,you can see in log-cat...

Comment: No errors that i can see...

Comment: Check on browser console for javascript error? And share full code with html?

Comment: Edited question with console output

Comment: [Google's example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-heatmap_weighted.html) works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive: `heatmapData` is not the same as `heatMapData`

You define:

```
 var heatmapData = [
```

But use:

```
var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
  data: heatMapData
});
```

The `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined heatmap:68` comes from the call to initialize before the API is loaded (you currently call it 3 times, you only need the one in the callback)

These two are extraneous:

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

  initialize();
```

Comment: Knew it would be something so silly!
Thanks for pointing out the redundant commands

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your are calling `initialize` at the end of your code and at that time google.maps is not yet loaded.

After that google maps calls once more `initialize` when it finished load.

You are executing too this line `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);` which is not useful since you added a callback when loading google.maps in the `loadScript` method there : `script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=visualization&`**callback=initialize'**;

So, remove this lines:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

initialize();
```

After that you have to conserve the case when using variables in JavaScript: `heatMapData` is not the same as `heatmapData`

That may resolve the errors. Try and come back if still does not work

Comment: Thanks for explaining the redundant commands!
The culprit was due to a miss named variabe